# Input string was not in a correct format with gridview update

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have this line of code

```
int Id = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewADMIN_Panel.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
```

Getting "Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Then the DataKey is not an integer, perhaps it's `null` or a `string`. Check what kind of data you are putting in the DataKeys.

Comment: Should I be using the "Id" in the dataset?

Comment: Yes, if that is the Unique Identifier. Usually it would be the `identity` column from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the `value` you are trying to cast is null or does not contain a valid integer. First you need to check if value is null and then caste value into int

```
if(GridViewADMIN_Panel.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0] != null)
  {
     //if value is not null then try to parse value into int
     int Id = Int.TryParse(GridViewADMIN_Panel.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);

  }
```

make sure, the value is int before you caste it.

Comment: My "Id" isn't an int....its a varchar....so can I make it any thing on the 4th as long as its an int?

Comment: do you get the row selected first ?

Comment: please share your function when you select from grid-view

Comment: The connectionstring?

Comment: So I need to make an entry that is an int to use for this.  My Id isn't an int its a varchar because it is a GUID.